# Paths in rectangular grid. Need some help with the logic behind it.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose I have a an ixj grid (i rows, j columns)

From the bottom left, to the top right, you may only move UP or RIGHT, how many paths are there from A to Z.

In this case, you must go up twice, right thrice, so my options are  ^^>>>
which gives $\frac{5!}{(3!2!)}$ arrangements.  or in the general case, $\frac{(i+j-2)!}{((i-1)!(j-1)!)}$ arrangements.

In the 3x4 case, that gives us 10 paths.

However, when I tried to look at the choices per node, and add them up, I got a different answer. Meaning, The first node has 2 choices, the moment you reach the top or right side, you have no more choices.

So if I add up the total choices, that would be 6? Similar discrepancies arise when I try larger grids.. however I always reach the correct answer with the combination method of ^^^^>>>> (which is a more mathematically sound one to me anyway) but I just wanted to get some insight on what is wrong in this situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to think of a coordinate system to stay on top of things.

2x3 grid:

02   12   22   32

01   11   21   31

00   10   20   30

The possible paths are:

10 20 30 31 32

10 20 21 31 32

10 20 21 22 32

10 11 21 31 32

10 11 21 22 32

10 11 12 22 32

01 11 21 31 32

01 11 21 22 32

01 11 12 22 32

01 02 12 22 32

10 paths in total.